# how to make visibility = View.GONE a certain view when launching a certain fragment when using navigation and BottomNavView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-viewbinding, android-navigationview

[main_actiity.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTnou.png)

[activity_main XML photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz4f5.png)

[main_fragment.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUON9.png)

[fragment_main XML photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GGuY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0BbT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done by subscribing to navigation component destination change listener, like this:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    if(destination.id = R.id.yourMainFragment) {
        // TODO hide/show your view here
    }
}
```

And then hiding/showing based on destination